# Create Allow/Block browser request on button click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, browser

I want to achieve it's the simplest form a button that when clicked prompts the user to allow/block the browser's request for location.

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDq8Y.jpg)

This does not need to function, or actually obtain the location of the visitor just evidence best practice when requesting sensitive user information such as their location.

Comment: Do you want to know how to trigger the browser's own prompt? 
The prompt itself comes from the browser, whenever the page tries to request the location. The prompt is not part of the html, but rather of the browser itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply using html and Javascript. You can make use of the `getCurrentPosition()` function. See this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) for complete example.

Here is a sample code of how you can achieve this:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this
        browser.";
    }
 }

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is specifically for obtaining your location.